# set checkbox cell selected in janus gridex from database

Tags: c#, janus

I have one table in Sql Server that have some fields .
4 fields has tinyint type that show active or not active some properties.
I want to show this fields In janus gridex checkbox cell (if value = 1 then cell is checked ).
How can i do this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dtc As DataTable = dt.Clone()
dtc.testColumn.DataType = GetType(Boolean)
```

After this you need to import all of the dt rows into dtc.

```
grd.DataSource = dtc
```

It's probably only solution.